# Finding the line containing a point at infinity and a point of the form $(x:y:1)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How do you find the line containing $(0:0:1)$ and $(1:2:0)$ that does not contain $(1:1:1)?$

I tried to use projective transformation, but I ended up getting the line $\ell(x,y,z)=z$ which I know is wrong since it does not contain $(0:0:1)$.

Please help!

Comment: Hint: every line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is given by an equation $aX + bY + cZ = 0$. Plug in the points to determine $a,b,c$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Feel free to write an answer to your question below when you solve it.

Comment: A line in the projective plane is uniquely determined by two points. If that third point happens to be on it as well, then you’re out of luck: there aren’t any other choices for the line.

Comment: As for how to find the line, take the cross product of the two points.